# Android post data via url

Tags: android, web-services, url, androidhttpclient

in my app i need to post data to an url to register a new user. Here is the url

```
http://myurl.com/user.php? email=[EMAIL]&username=[USERNAME]&password[PASS]&img_url=[IMG]
```

If I do that correctly I should get this message:

```
{"success":true,"error":null} 
or if not {"success":false,"error":"parameters"}
```

Can somebody guide me through this and tell me how can I do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first :
you need to perform all network tasks in an Async thread using:

```
public class PostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
{
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //put all your network code here
}
```

Second:
create your http request:
i am assuming email, username and IMG as variables over here.

```
    String server ="http://myurl.com/user.php? email=[" + EMAIL + "]&username=[" + USERNAME + "]&password[" + PASS + "]&img_url=["+IMG + "]";

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(server);

            //httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            //httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

third:     
// Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JSONdata", Object));     
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));

            try {
                HttpResponse response =httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Now simple query your response handler i.e. response in this case.

Don't forget to add INTERNET permission in your androidManifest.xml

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [HTTP client](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) class, and format your URL via a specific [URI constructor.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html#URI%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) Create a [HTTP post](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html), optionally set the entity, headers, etc, execute the post via the client, receive a [HTTP response](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html), pull the [entity](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) out of the response and process it.

EDIT for example:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
URI uri = new URI("http",  
        "www.google.com",  // connecting to  IP
        "subpath", // and the "path" of what we want
        "a=5&b=6", // query 
        null); // no fragment
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri.toASCIIString);
// have a body ?
// post.setEntity(new StringEntity(JSONObj.toString()));
// post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
Reader r = new  InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
// Do something with the data in the reader.
```

Comment: Can you give me an example how to do it?